# Cannot use del key to delete files on desktop in 20.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04

I just did a clean install of 20.04 and I noticed that no key shortcuts for files manipulation work when my focus in on Desktop (not in Nautilus).

When I have copied a file to clipboard, I cannot <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> it to Desktop, when I click on a file on Desktop, I cannot <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it, or I cannot <kbd>Delete</kbd> it with keys. Only ways to do it is either navigate to the Desktop folder in Nautilus, or right-click the file on the Desktop and copy/move to trash/paste...

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, all the key shortcuts worked normally for me in 18.04.

Comment: I believe this is one of the features that should not be in the first place.

Comment: I am also facing the same on clean install of 20.04

Comment: Answered here askubuntu.com/a/1240666/24700

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately desktop icons are completely broken, which is quite unexpected in a LTS release of Ubuntu.

You just cannot use keyboard on desktop icons (I'm not kidding).

This has been reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1868924).

The workaround is described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1868924/comments/4).

1. Remove gnome-desktop-icons
2. Install nemo
3. Make nemo handle desktop icons

Comment: Wonderful ! From that comment, keyboard navigation has not been implemented at all, so this will not be fixed soon -_-
This is quite disappointing from a major Linux distribution, I had got many bugs with Ubuntu recently, it seems that relyability is no longer the standard...
https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons/-/issues/31#note_797279

Comment: If minor bugs are a major problem it is best to always wait 6 months before installing a new version of Ubuntu, in my opinion, and from what I have learned since Jaunty Jackalope, might not be as true nowadays as it was.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What does it mean "make nemo handle desktop icons"?

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm that issue has been fixed in **gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 20.04.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1**

This is available via the proposed apt channel. [Here's how to enable it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed).

After enabling it, you install the package by doing the regular `apt update && apt upgrade`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Dell XPS 15

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Mee, the best solution is to replace the Gnome Shell "desktop-icons" extension, and use the Nemo desktop instead:

```sh
# install Nemo
sudo apt install nemo

# Edit settings
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true

# Disable the "desktop-icons" extension
gnome-extensions disable desktop-icons@csoriano

# Set nemo-desktop to autostart on login
cp /usr/share/applications/nemo-autostart.desktop $HOME/.config/autostart/
sed -i -r 's/^(OnlyShowIn)/#\1/i' $HOME/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart.desktop
```

You may need to reboot after the change for it to take effect (see comment below)

(My [other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346063/8822) also adds some details)

Comment: This hid everything from desktop view and made it unusable. At least ~/Desktop exists with all files.

Comment: @DawidLaszuk : maybe you didn't run the last "sed ..." line, which is essential. See the other answer I linked to for more details.

Comment: I have run everything and it didn't work but that's because I haven't restarted OS. Thought that log out and restart DM would be enough - it wasn't. If you add necessity for restarting OS after changes, then I can change my vote to +1. Thanks :)

Comment: @DawidLaszuk: Updated. I don't understand what would make it need a full reboot, but apparently it is sometimes. Thanks for the tip,